# A "no" is needed here, no es cierto?

Tags: traducción

In the book "Smart Spanish for Tontos Americanos" it gives this:

```
I haven't been able to raise all the money for the project, but I'm not giving up
```

...as the translation for this:

```
No he logrado conseguir suficiente dinero para el proyecto, pero me doy por vencido
```

But if the English is correct, shouldn't there be a "no" there in the Spanish, such as:

```
No he logrado conseguir suficiente dinero para el proyecto, pero me no doy por vencido
```

-or:

```
No he logrado conseguir suficiente dinero para el proyecto, pero no me doy por vencido
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the book's answer is wrong and the `me no doy por vencido` is also wrong the right one is your second example:

> No he logrado conseguir suficiente dinero para el proyecto, pero **no** me doy por vencido.

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct translation is not so literal:

"No he logrado conseguir suficiente dinero para el proyecto, pero no me **daré** por vencido"

That was you have to reforce are talking about the future.

Comment: Agreed. This translations sounds way more natural in my dialect.